# How to describe this set geometrically?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So, we know that $$e^z ≡ e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$$ for $z=x+iy$. Now, let $D$ be the set of all points in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^z$ takes real values.

According to my understanding, $e^z$ would take real values only when $i\sin(y)=0$, i.e., when $y=n\pi$. Now I can write it out in a set just like that, but how would I describe this geometrically...? I'm kind of confused there, if anyoneee can help. Also, please correct me if what I've written above is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Use $\sin$ and $\cos$ (and the same with other common functions) to get better looking formulas

Comment: Ohh ok, I'll keep that in mind from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just described an infinite family of parallel horizontal lines. There's the axis itself, and then the lines given by vertical translation by $n\pi$.